# 2d array with function javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I've task to create function that will display names from 2d array (const users). Each name should be displayed in separate line in console. Here is the code I've prepared but not sure if it's correct?

```js
const users = [["Jaydn Humphries", "Ayda Orozco"], ["Sanjeev Wilkinson", "Jorge Markham"]];

function print2DArray(array) {
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            console.log(array[i][j]);
        }
    }return array;
}
print2DArray(users);
```

Comment: Define "not sure if it's correct"? That's not a real problem

Comment: I wanted to know if I wrote it properly according to task as I receive in console: Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined

Comment: There's no `module` anywhere in the code you posted. That's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner for loop should run on the inner array not on the outer array.
i.e. j should be looped up to array[i].length not array.length

Although since in your example the inner arrays have the same length as the outer array, your example should work just fine.

Comment: The same lengths seems like a coincidence, so it just happens to work fine in this case.